# overflow text not aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new with html and css and this could be a trivial question.
I'm using this code:

html code:

```
<div class="container" >

  <div class="row">
    <fieldset class="for-panel">
      <legend>Project Info</legend>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-horizontal">
            <label class="col-xs-5 control-label">Name:</label>
            <p class="form-control-static">Batman</p> 
           <label class="col-xs-5 control-label">Description: </label>
            <p class="form-control-static">Batman is a fictional superhero appearing in American comic books published by DC Comics. The character was created by artist Bob Kane and writer Bill Finger,[4][5] and first appeared in Detective Comics #27 (1939). Originally named the "Bat-Man", the character is also referred to by such epithets as the Caped Crusader, the Dark Knight, and the World's Greatest Detective.[6]</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-horizontal">
            <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">Name: </label>
            <p class="form-control-static">Joker </p>


            <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">Description:</label>
            <p class="form-control-static">The Joker is a fictional supervillain created by Bill Finger, Bob Kane, and Jerry Robinson who first appeared in the debut issue of the comic book Batman (April 25, 1940) published by DC Comics. Credit for the Joker's creation is disputed; Kane and Robinson claimed responsibility for the Joker's design, while acknowledging Finger's writing contribution. Although the Joker was planned to be killed off during his initial appearance, he was spared by editorial intervention, allowing the character to endure as the archenemy of the superhero Batman.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
fieldset.for-panel {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:15px 10px;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
  background-color: #f9fdfd;
  margin-bottom:12px;
}
fieldset.for-panel legend {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #4381ba;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin: inherit;
  padding: 7px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#containerProjectInfo{

  margin-top: 1%;
  width:90%;


}
```

This is the result [image](https://screenshot.net/zqexnfg)

but it doesn't work like I would. In the descriptions when there is an overflow text, the rows are not aligned but start at the bottom of the description label. 
I tried to used `ord-wrap: break-word` but without result.

Thank you

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive, I didn't quite understand what you willing to do.

Comment: Sorry but it is difficult to explain for me...I would like to have the text aligned where there are the black lines in this picture [image](https://screenshot.net/rdv9paj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has 12 Column and when you divide them they has another 12 column inside. Use `<div class="row">` and make the column division correctly, it should be alright. Always separate parts within a container/row.
I've only modified the HTML codes. CSS Unchanged!

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <fieldset class="for-panel">
        <legend>Project Info</legend>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- First Column -->
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row"> <!-- name row -->
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <label>Name:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <p>Batman</p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <label>Description: </label> <!-- description row -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <p>Batman is a fictional superhero appearing in American comic books published by DC Comics. The character was created by artist Bob Kane and writer Bill Finger,[4][5] and first appeared in Detective Comics #27 (1939). Originally named the "Bat-Man", the character is also referred to by such epithets as the Caped Crusader, the Dark Knight, and the World's Greatest Detective.[6]</p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Second Column -->
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">  <!-- name row -->
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <label>Name:</label> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <p>Joker</p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">  <!-- description row -->
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <label>Description: </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <p>The Joker is a fictional supervillain created by Bill Finger, Bob Kane, and Jerry Robinson who first appeared in the debut issue of the comic book Batman (April 25, 1940) published by DC Comics. Credit for the Joker's creation is disputed; Kane and Robinson claimed responsibility for the Joker's design, while acknowledging Finger's writing contribution. Although the Joker was planned to be killed off during his initial appearance, he was spared by editorial intervention, allowing the character to endure as the archenemy of the superhero Batman.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

This should fix your issue, however I've also removed the classes for the names since it had some padding to it which didn't align the text correctly. You may add it back and fix the css.

Hope this help you out.

More reference about Bootstrap Table can be found here: [Click Me](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Image Preview: [image]